# Alias to open last file edited in Vim

Tags: bash, vim, alias, 19.10

I am running Ubuntu 19.10, and I am trying to alias the command "vv" to open the last edited file in Vim. Below is my results from running the command 'alias'.

```
~/Documents/code$ alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias cls='clear'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias sl='ls --color=auto'
alias vv='!vi'
```

I receive the error:

```
~/Documents/code$ vv
Command '!vi' not found, but there are 15 similar ones.
```

!v and !vi are already working commands to open the last edited file in Vim, but I want vv to also be a command to do the same function, because sometimes I'm lazy.

Things I've tried:

- Updating ~/.bashrc with new alias
- Restarting computer
- Open new terminal

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) is performed *before* [alias expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Alias).

You can force history expansion in your alias by using the `history` command, using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) to replace a command that queries the history with its output:

```
alias vv='$(history -p !vim)'
```

but this will not handle filenames correctly if they contain characters that might trigger an expansion, such as spaces. You can avoid this using [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-eval):

```
alias vv='eval $(history -p !vim)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
alias vv="vim -c 'norm! ^O'"
```

`norm` execute normal mode command `^O` as if you type it. See `:help :normal` for more information.

`^O` is one character, you can input it in insert mode by typing `<C-V><C-O>`. It brings you to last cursor position, which is in the last file you edited.

So the alias above is the same as opening vim and press ctrl-o.